# Cakephp 4 : How to save hasone data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two database table 1) users 2) profiles

profiles has a field called bank_ac

I am trying to save it from user model.

I have created form input like

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
   <?= $this->Form->control('profile.bank_ac'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

User model I have added associative like

```
$this->hasOne('Profiles');
```

After debug getting data like

```
[
    'name' => 'Jone',
    'email' => 'abcd@yahoo.com',
    'profile' => [
        'bank_ac' => '1212212'
    ]
]
```

after debug patch entity

```
object(App\Model\Entity\User) {

    'name' => 'Jone',
    'email' => 'abcd@yahoo.com',
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'profile' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Users'

}
```

In UsersController/add I have applied code like

```
public function add(){

        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());

        $this->Users->save($user, ['associated' => ['Profiles']]);

}
```

Profile data not saving , also not getting any error. How can I save this associative data ?

Comment: For further insight, debug your patched `$user` entity.

Comment: Updated my  question, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your entity debug result, the `profile` field is missing from the accessibility config, hence disallowing its use in mass assignment (patching).

Add it to your `User::$_accessible` property, and it should work:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    // ...
    'profile' => true,
];
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Mass Assignment](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)**

Comment: @NiloyRony Depends on how the entity is built (manually, with user data, etc), and generally how much you can trust the process that creates the entity. Technically if you consider the entity creation process to be safe (ie users aren't able to assign data that you don't want them to be able to save in a specific action), then you wouldn't need to restrict the saving process.

Comment: @NiloyRony However first level associations can be patched and saved by default, so unwanted data slipping in can happen easily if something in your entity creation process changes, so that you might want to use the `associated` option for both, patching and saving, that way even when a supposedly safe entity turns out to be not trustworthy, saving would still be restricted.